# Typescript, xml2js, explicitArray - how to deal with child nodes

Tags: typescript, xml2js

I use [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) to translate one type of XML into an object in Typescript. With its `explicitArray` option, xml2js forces users to either always generate arrays for nodes (`explicitArray=true`), or make array generation depending on the number of
elements of this type read from the XML (`explicitArray=false`): If more than one, it becomes an array.

In order to work with the resulting object, I'm implementing interfaces and constants (currently 200 lines, likely to double). It typically
looks like this:

```javascript
export interface Foo {
    apiVersion: string,
    bar: Bar[],
    label: string,
    menus: string[]
}
```

Up until now I've worked with the default, i.e. child nodes are always arrays, but this setting becomes tedious, when only about 20% of elements can actually
appear several times in the XML. I'm still relatively new to Typescript. Can you recommend a setting of `explicitArray`?

Are there standard strategies to deal with this problem?

Or maybe I've overlooked something?